# scipy.stats: no module named _ufuncs

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I tried installing a new version of scipy and after following the instructions I got it to work, but as soon as I import the scipy.stats I receive the error "Import Error: no module named _ufuncs". How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Your scipy install is broken. Best wipe it clean and start from scratch. The rest depends on how you install it.